# Saving files in a loop with generic file name

Tags: file, powershell, csv, save, filenames

How can I loop through a list of files, perform an operation and save the file to a new location with a name from a list?

As an example I have a list of CSV files, and a list of new names, I would like to do a simple operation on the CSV file like changing the delimiter and save each file to a new location with a new name from the list of names. How can I set the save path and new name correctly?

```
$files = Get-ChildItem C:\folder\*.csv
$te = Import-Csv C:\names.csv
For ($i=0; $i -lt $te.Length;$i++){
    Import-Csv $file -Delimiter "|" | Export-Csv -Path C:\another_folder\$te[$i].csv -Delimiter ","
}
```

To be precise, the problem is that the save path after the `-Path` statement is incorrect. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to *wrap* the path with *quotes*:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem C:\folder\*.csv
$te = Import-Csv C:\names.csv
For ($i=0; $i -lt $te.Length;$i++){
    Import-Csv $file -Delimiter "|" | Export-Csv -Path "C:\another_folder\$te[$i].csv" -Delimiter ","
}
```